# Laravel is giving me Undefined variable Error Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
        <? $counter = 1 ?>

        <div id="container_blog_all">
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <div class="blog_block" style="@if($counter % 3 == 0) margin-right:0px @endif">
                    <a href="{{ $post->url() }}"><img class="blog_block_cover" src="{{ URL::to('uploads/blog/cover/'.$post->cover) }}"></a>
                    <div class="blog_block_date">{{ $post->date }}</div>
                    <div class="blog_block_sep"></div>
                    <div class="blog_block_title">{{ $post->title }}</div>
                </div>
                <? $counter++; ?>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

And I am getting this error, any reasons why??

[image]

I can see the the variable counter is defined, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

`<? $counter = 1 ?>`

should be

`<? $counter = 1; ?>`

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters or not, but you might try `<?php ?>` instead of just `<? ?>`  Also, what line is it giving the error on?  I'm assuming `<? counter++; ?>`

Comment: Thank you, was the <?php thing, weird! cause this only happens locally. But Thank You!!!

Comment: I think that's new in Laravel 4 (although I can find where I read that).  Glad it's working for you :)

Comment: Try not to use PHP short tags. They aren't supported across all versions of PHP and are generally a bad habit to get into. Opening tags for "echoing" such as `<?=`, however, I believe are fairly supported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like laravel doesn't like php short tags, it is better you use `<?php $counter = 1 ?>` rather than `<? $counter = 1 ?>`.That should resolve the error also.